# running Save method to get newly generated _id back

Tags: c#, mongodb

If I have a collection with _id of ObjectId type and I do not generate it on my own before calling Collection.Save method, Save is supposed to generate it for me. The question is: does the Save method always return you back newly generated _id for every type of WriteConcern?

As an example I can do this in c#:

```
public ObjectId Save(entity)
{
   Collection.Save(entity);
   return entity.Id
}
```

will I always get back generated _id regardless of WriteConcern settings and any other factors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when calling save(), you'll always get back the 'upserted' id (i.e., existing _id in case of an update, and the generated _id in case of an insert).

I'm not familiar with the C# api.  In Java, the [save()](https://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#save-com.mongodb.DBObject-) method returns an object of type [WriteResult](https://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html), which has a helper method named [getUpsertedId()](https://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html#getUpsertedId--) which will return the _id value of an upserted document.

From the documentation:

> Gets the _id value of an upserted document that resulted from this write. Note that for MongoDB servers prior to version 2.6, this method will return null unless the _id of the upserted document was of type ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `.Save` is a [WriteConcernResult](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.10.0/html/7957aaa1-ecd4-3de6-d5b5-698cada99487.htm) access the `.Upserted property to see the`_id` value from the newly created document:

```
public ObjectId Save(entity)
{
   WriteConcernResult result = Collection.Save(entity);
   return result.Upserted
}
```

Comment: This property `result.Upserted` is always null to me after Save call, weather I generate Id manually with `ObjectId.GenerateNewId()` or pass it as null. No errors happen in both cases and document successfully updated or inserted in database. Mongodb c# driver 1.10

Comment: @YMC try logging the entire result object and make sure that you are not matching an existing document.

Comment: @Nail Lunn According to profile regular `insert` operation is generated as result of running `Save` method with new `ObjectId`. `WriteConcernResult` properties: `Ok: true`, `DocumentsAffected : 0`, `HasLastErrorMessage: false`, `UpdatedExisting: false`, `Upserted: null`